# niginx configuration simpification of location directives

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration, rewrite

I have the following (redacted for simplicity) nginx config:

```
server{
        location ~ /saml/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_send_timeout 300;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            send_timeout 300;
            proxy_pass https://acme.com;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_send_timeout 300;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            send_timeout 300;
            proxy_pass https://acme.com;
        }
}
```

As you can see I have two locations defined. The only difference between the two is that any URL containing /SAML/* won't get the `try_files` line.

Everything else is the same. Is there a cleaner, more manageable way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many directives in Nginx can be inherited from the surrounding context. You only need the `proxy_pass` and `try_files` statements within the specific `location` blocks.

For example:

```
server{
    root ...;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;

    location ~ /saml/ {
        proxy_pass https://acme.com;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_pass https://acme.com;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, place common statements into a separate file and use an `include` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.